# Image of Borel set under countable-to-one Borel function is Borel.

Tags: reference-request, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Suppose that $ X, Y $ are Polish spaces, $ A \subset X $ is Borel, $ f : X \to Y $ is Borel, and furthermore, $ f $ is countable-to-one: i.e., $ \forall y \in Y: | f^{-1}(y) | \leq \aleph_0 $. Is it true that $ f(A) $ is Borel?

If $ f $ is injective, this is a corollary of the Lusin-Suslin theorem (see Theorem 15.2 in Kechris).

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Thanks @Saad, I added the tag `reference-request` and modified the question. I haven't tried to prove it, as it is the extension of an already deep theorem.

Comment: More generally, this works for a $\sigma$-compact-to-one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This appears as Exercise 18.14 of the same book, and is a consequence of Lusin-Novikov theorem, that states that a projection of a Borel subset of $X\times Y$ with countable sections, is Borel.

The statement of that exercise says that $f(X)$ is Borel, but any Borel $A\subseteq X$ is a standard Borel space with the relative $\sigma$-algebra, and hence admits a Polish topology for which $f\restriction A$ is also Borel, and the result follows.